# Auto Checkbox Item Generation

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Screenshot1]

Hi everyone,

I've been stuck at this for some time... I hope someone could enlighten me on this. So, I have created a 4 list boxes over here (ActiveX) and I am hoping to create checkboxes within each list box so that each time I can hide/unhide an excel sheet from the same workbook just by selecting it. However, I have too many tabs in the workbook alone. Also, these tabs are all sort of like `Warehouse 1`, `Warehouse 2`, `Security 1`,`Security 2`, etc etc. So there's sort of like a common name before these numbers.

I was wondering if there's anyway to auto generate the checkboxes in accordance to the tab names?

For example, if i select `1` under the **Warehouse** listbox, it should link over to the tab `Warehouse 1` in the workbook.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I have an idea... will test when on my pc.

Comment: Thanks so much Samuel! I really really appreciate it!

Comment: Before I start, what have you tried already? Whether it works or not, even if you have an idea or pseudo code (though preferred not) for what you want to happen, you should always include an example of your code you have tried.

Comment: Hey Samuel! Attached below is the link I've tried to recreate for hiding and unhiding the sheets! I've been doing this initially for every single page; until i found the lovely list box! However, now the issue is: 1) How do I mass create the checkboxes within the listbbox according to the scenario as described above; since i've got loads of sheets to repeat that code for... Not sure if this is helpful at all, but i really appreciate your keen interest in helping me out! :) Link: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4148-excel-checkbox-hide-unhide-sheet.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal you will first need to make some changes to the properties of the `listbox` on the sheet.

Enter *design mode* and *right click* the `listbox` > Properties.

Change the following properties:

- *'ListStyle'* to **1 - fmListStyleOption**
- *'MultiSelect'* to **1 - fmMultiSelectMulti**

The ListStyle change will put option buttons to the left of each list entry and the MultiSelect adjustment will change the option buttons to checkboxes.

Here is some sample code to populate the `ListBox` with the Worksheet names - I have assumed your worksheet containing the `ListBox` is named  `"Main"` *AND* I have named the `"Generate CheckBox"` button `cmdGenerateCheckBox`.

```
Private Sub cmdGenerateCheckBox_Click()

Dim WorksheetArray() As Variant
Dim WorksheetIndex As Long
Dim ArrayElement As Variant
Dim NumberOfSheets As Long
Dim MainSheet As Object

Set MainSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")

NumberOfSheets = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
ReDim WorksheetArray(1 To NumberOfSheets)

For WorksheetIndex = 1 To UBound(WorksheetArray)
    WorksheetArray(WorksheetIndex) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WorksheetIndex).Name
Next WorksheetIndex

MainSheet.lstWarehouse.Clear
MainSheet.lstSecurity.Clear

For Each ArrayElement In WorksheetArray()
    If ArrayElement Like "Warehouse*" Then
        MainSheet.lstWarehouse.AddItem ArrayElement
    ElseIf ArrayElement Like "Security*" Then
        MainSheet.lstSecurity.AddItem ArrayElement
    End If
Next ArrayElement

Dim ListItemCounter As Long
Dim ListItem As Variant

'----------------lstWarehouse ListBox-----------------
ListItemCounter = 0
For Each ListItem In MainSheet.lstWarehouse.List
    For Each ArrayElement In WorksheetArray()
        If ListItem = ArrayElement Then
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ArrayElement).Visible = True Then
                MainSheet.lstWarehouse.Selected(ListItemCounter) = True
            ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ArrayElement).Visible = False Then
                MainSheet.lstWarehouse.Selected(ListItemCounter) = False
            End If
        Else
            'Do nothing
        End If
    Next ArrayElement
    ListItemCounter = ListItemCounter + 1
Next ListItem

'----------------lstSecurity ListBox-----------------
ListItemCounter = 0
For Each ListItem In MainSheet.lstSecurity.List
    For Each ArrayElement In WorksheetArray()
        If ListItem = ArrayElement Then
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ArrayElement).Visible = True Then
                MainSheet.lstSecurity.Selected(ListItemCounter) = True
            ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ArrayElement).Visible = False Then
                MainSheet.lstSecurity.Selected(ListItemCounter) = False
            End If
        Else
            'Do nothing
        End If
    Next ArrayElement
    ListItemCounter = ListItemCounter + 1
Next ListItem

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks! I will try it out just in a moment later. And yes, I've already changed the properties already! So the screenshot that was posted in the question (the listboxes) are already set in accordance to the ones you've said. I'll try out the codes next. Let me keep you posted on it. I sincerely thank you so much for the time taken :))

Comment: The code in it's current state does not manipulate the visibility of each sheet (but does create the checkbox regardless of if a sheet is visible or not.

Comment: Hey Samuel, when i tried the code, it says 'Object doesn't support this property or method'. Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: It didn't show any 'End' or 'Debug' option. By any chance would you have the file you've worked on? I could probably refer to it; if that's all possible. Thanks! :) (reachjoshng@gmail.com)

Comment: You can step through the code with F8 in the VBE. Try that first and then we will see which line is causing the issue.

Comment: This line of code isn't working : ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").lstWarehouse.Clear

Comment: @JoshNg I've edited the answer as follows: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")` is now assigned to variable `MainSheet` to make the code a bit cleaner. I've also added an additional 2 loops at the end which will either select or deselect each list item check based on the visibility of it's corresponding sheet.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Firstly, I would like to thank Samuel for his precious time taken off to help me solve this issue. Without his patience, this wouldn't have been possible!

Secondly, just to add onto Samuel's answer, you HAVE TO change the name of the listboxes. So for example, **1stWarehouse**, **1stSecurity**. By changing name, it means to go over to properties and change (as seen on the screenshot).

Comment: Be careful not to confuse the lowercase L with the number 1 (as lowercase L in the VBE looks like the number 1).